# Узнать, выходит ли конкретный Item за границу View

Tags: qt, c++

У меня есть несколько `QGraphicsItem'ов` в `QGraphicsView`. Я отключил появление `scroll bar` когда они не умещаются в `View`. Но некоторые могут выходить за границу `View`. Как мне узнать, выходит ли конкретный `Item` за границу `View`. Уверен, что есть какой-то метод в `QGraphicsItem` или `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: ведь сама qt как-то узнаёт, что элемент вышел за пределы видимости и показывает scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Если я не ошибаюсь, то того что Вы хотите можно добиться несколькими способами:

1) Использовать у `QGraphicsItem` метод:  `virtual QRectF boundingRect () const = 0`.

Этот метод возвращает ограничивающий прямоугольник объекта QGraphicsItem.
Затем, используя `QPolygon mapFromScene ( const QRectF & rect )` у `QGraphicsView` получить координаты в системе окна и проверить попадает ли полученный прямоугольник в координаты окна, используя contains(). В этом случае проверка будет быстрой, но не точной.

2) Использовать у `QGraphicsItem` метод:  `virtual QPainterPath shape() const`, и повторить все как в первом пункте. В этом случае проверка будет более точной, но и более медленной.

В любом случае Вам необходимо будет иметь дело с преобразованиями из координат сцены в координаты окна и наоборот.

Comment: спасибо, решил проблему первым методом)